# how to install a particular laravel version: When i try its giving error

Tags: laravel

I have a project with

```
const VERSION = '5.1.26 (LTS)'; (inside "vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php")
```

And my php and composer are

```
% php --version
PHP 7.0.7 (cli) (built: May 25 2016 18:40:26) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

% composer --version
Composer version 1.1.2 2016-05-31 19:48:11
```

I am trying to install laravel version `5.1.26 (LTS)` in the below ways:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel my_project 5.1.26
```

and also

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.1.26 science --prefer-dist
```

Both says the same error:

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.1.26. in phar:///usr/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/CreateProjectCommand.php:310
```

How to install the old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project_name "5.1.*"
```

Comment: but will it install 5.1.26 or any other.

Comment: 5.1.latest version

Comment: I have a composer.json from a project. How to install laravel and create a project using that

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter order is wrong. Try below one.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel sacredindiaapp 5.1.* --prefer-dist
```

It should work.

Comment: Why to use --prefer-dist

Comment: Here is a detailed description for --prefer-dist

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Answer (score 0):

Try this and this will work for you ... :)

```
   composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.1 science --prefer-dist
```

Comment: just remove `.26` at the end of the `version 5.1.26` and run it ... it will work in both cases ...